What is (considered) the best double hybrid functional?
I am curious what is considered the best among the double hybrid functionals to date, if any?

What do you mean by "best"? Does this answer your question?

What property are you interested in? The answer to your question will depend a lot on whether you are interested in the ground state energy, excited state energy, singlet-triplet gap, or electronic density.

Well, perhaps, I would choose, in (reproducing) electronic density.
